# Batch file to delete keyword in text file

Tags: batch-file, replace

I have a text file that looks something like this:

```
P4657_1
P1352_1
P3126_1
```

and so on.

I need a batch script that removes the "P" at the beginning and the "_1" at the end.
I found many script examples in this forum but none worked for my needs.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Please explain more, are all "keywords" at one line? What have you tried, please show your code here.

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -E 's/^P//g; s/_1$//g' yourinfile > outfile
```

by virtue of the first substitution beginning P's get nuked, by the second final _1's get nuked and you are done.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm using windows so i'm not sure I can use sed.

Comment: download cygwin (it is free) and you have everything (sed, bash, awk,...) and a whole new world ahead of you.

Answer (score 0):

For a list of options for modifying text files, see [How can you find and replace text in a file using the Windows command-line environment?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60034/1012053).

My favorite option is a [hybrid JScript/batch utility I wrote called REPL.BAT](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16735079/1012053). The script does not require installation of any 3rd party executables, and it will run on any modern version of Windows, starting with XP.

Using REPL.BAT, the solution is as simple as:

```
type "yourFile.txt" | repl "^P(.*)_1$" "$1" >yourFile.txt.new
move /y "yourFile.txt.new" "yourFile.txt" >nul
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to everyone.
I did find a solution elsewhere: http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=1498

the code is very simple:

```
set "search=P"
set "replace="
for /F "delims=" %%a in (input.txt) DO (
   set line=%%a
   setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
   >> output2.txt echo(!line:%search%=%replace%!
   endlocal
)
```

Comment: How does this remove the `_1` bit?

Comment: It doesn't. I use another block of code like this to replace the _1

Answer (score 0):

You can use [echo](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-replace.html) apparently. So, print your file with [type](http://ss64.com/nt/type.html), and [for](http://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html) each line, assign the line to a variable, edit the variable, and then echo the variable.